# Asp Gridview Change Layout when open a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2013

Good morning,
I have a really strange problem. I created an ASP project using Visual Studio 2013 and I inserted a simple GridView. Then I added a button that allow me to open a modal window with another aspx page. The problem is that when open the modal window, the gridview in the parent page change layout. This is the code:

**Home.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

</div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GymSessionID" HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SessionDate" HeaderText="Date" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

**Home.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            TestSimoneEntities ent = new TestSimoneEntities();
            GridView1.DataSource = ent.GymSession.ToList();
            GridView1.DataBind();   
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string script = @"<script language='javascript'>javascript: window.open('http://www.microsoft.com', null, 'scrollbars=1,width=600,HEIGHT=400');</script>";
        Response.Write(script.ToString());
    }
```

**Dialog.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

</div>
</form>
```

**Dialog.aspx.cs**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string script = @"<script>

    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        var loc = window.opener.location;
        window.opener.location = loc;

    }
</script>";
        Response.Write(script.ToString());

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "text";
    }
}
```

As you can see the code is really simple but the gridview changes layout

Answer (score 1):

For who is interested I solved this problem.
The only thing that I changed is this line:

string script = @"javascript: window.open('http://www.microsoft.com', null, 'scrollbars=1,width=600,HEIGHT=400');";
        Response.Write(script.ToString());

into this:

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    GetType(),
    "MyKey",
    "window.open('http://www.microsoft.com', null, 'scrollbars=1,width=600,HEIGHT=400');",
    true);

I don't really understand why this happen but in this way I solved my problem.